# Use unicode characters for Xmonad workspaces

Tags: haskell, unicode, xmonad

I want to use Unicode characters from the [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) for my workspaces in Xmonad.

```
myWorkspaces = ["1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:ﱘ", "7:", "8:", "9:"]
```

For reference:

[image: Array of workspace Unicode names]

However, I get the following error on compilation:

```
xmonad.hs:191:13: error:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character '\62057'
    |
191 |         ["1:", "2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:ﱘ", "7:", "8:", "9:"]
    |             ^

Please check the file for errors.

Warning: Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion
```

Is there any chance to use a full set of nerd fonts unicode characters? I have seen that others use a subset of unicode in [their config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27742421/3250126).

Comment: What is the encoding of your source files? Have you tried to specify the symbols with escape sequence?

Comment: @max630, I am using `file -i xmonad.hs: xmonad.hs: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. What would be the escape sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're running into [GHC bug #5518](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/5518). As a workaround, try the escape syntax instead (e.g., `"1:\62057"` or `"1:\xf269"` instead of `"1:"`).

Comment: awesome, thanks. You could add that that it is easy to use the second approach and extracting the hex value from nerdfonts.com

Comment: Maybe worth noting that, while this is *related* to bug #5518, this behavior isn't actually a bug.  The Haskell standards and GHC require that string literals contain only "graphic" unicode characters (letters, marks, numbers, punctation, symbols. and spaces, corresponding to Unicode categories L, M, N, P, S, and Zs, and that excludes most of the characters above (which are designated as "private use" or category Co).

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I'd argue that it's still a bug, just a bug in the standard rather than in the implementation.